# MVC c# - need to do POST only once on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I am using MVC 3, c# on IE9 
In my controller I have the following 2 ActionResuls that is of significance:

```
    public ActionResult EditTrain(String trainid)
    {
       ....
       return PartialView(edittrain);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTrain(Train editrain)
    {
       ....
       DataContext.SubmitChanges();      
       return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = trainid });                  
    }
```

On the partial view, I have the following code:

```
    @model Models.EditTrain
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Training";
    }

    <h2>Train</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "theForm" }))
    {
      @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

      <div class="display-label" style="font-weight: normal">
       @Html.Label("ID:")
      </div>
      <div class="display-field">
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
      </div>   

      <div class="display-label" style="font-weight: normal">
        @Html.Label("KitID:")
      </div>
      <div class="display-field">
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.KitID)
      </div> 

      <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.Label("Inactive:")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Inactive)
      </div>    

      <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.Label("Inactive Date:")
     </div>   

     <div id='datepicker' class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InactiveDate)
     </div> 
      ......
      <div style="clear:left;"> 
       <br />         
       <p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
       </p>
      </div> 
    }  

   <script type="text/javascript">

   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 

   $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#submit").click(function () {

       $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $('#theForm').serialize()
             });

       $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("KitsEdit","Spr")' + '?id=' +  '@Model.sprid');

     });
   });
```

In the above code, what I like to happen above is that once the user clicks on submit, I like it to go to the following action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTrain(Train editrain)
```

and then return back to the View and run the following code

```
       $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("KitsEdit","Spr")' + '?id=' +  '@Model.sprid');
```

What is happening though is that it does the above but after it runs

```
    $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("KitsEdit","Spr")' + '?id=' +  '@Model.sprid');
```

it runs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTrain(Train editrain)
```

a second time.

How can I prevent it from going to

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTrain(Train editrain)
```

after the .load().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `false` from your `.click()` handler. But looking at your code there is something conceptually wrong with it. You call the `.load` method immediately after firing off your AJAX request without even waiting for this AJAX request to finish. Also there is very little point in invoking a controller action that does a redirect to another action using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I added  async: false, I believe this is what was needed, correct?

Comment: That's even worse. Simply remove this AJAX call. Setting `async: false` will freeze the browser during the call creating one of the worst user experiences ever. If you want to use AJAX, then it should be asynchronous. If not, simply use a standard form submission.

Comment: Sorry Darin, I could not follow you. When you said You call the .load method immediately after firing off your AJAX request without even waiting for this AJAX request to finish, I thought async: false would fix it. In my case, I need to do a POST and then the load(). If you can clarify. Thanks

Comment: When I posted my answer I didn't know that you was using `async: false`. That is nowhere shown in your code. But as I said, using `async: false` makes things worse. Simply design a controller action that will do the required processing and return the necessary partial view. Then send a normal AJAX request (without any `async:false`) to this controller action and inject the resulting partial into your DOM. You don't need 2 requests. A single one, and properly done (asynchronously) should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **request.Abort()**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#submit").click(function () {

       var request = $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $('#theForm').serialize()
             });

       $("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("KitsEdit","Spr")' + '?id=' +  '@Model.sprid');
request.Abort()
     });
   });
```

Comment: I used request.Abort() it gave an error. Browser didn't know what request Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'request' is undefined